# Is there a site or app where you can get examples of code assignments?

Tags: php, frontend

Okey, so here I'm learning coding (mostly PHP, and frontend dev). And I would like to know if there is a site where I can get an assignment like "make a calculator" or similar.

So I can get inspiration for small projects while I'm learning. Learning by doing so to speak.
I don't want big projects. Something that I can make in one evening.

I have googled around but with no luck.

TL;DR, is there a site were I can find inspiration for small coding projects (PHP).

Comment: create CRUD applicatoin Like Login,User Roles,Authenticaton,Permission, Then play with Javascript, Modals,Ajax,Dynamic Tables NOTE: these are all small projects, Combine them have an application ;)

Comment: You can try this course http://cs75.tv/2012/summer/

Answer (score 1):

IMO [Github](https://www.github.com) is the best website to find projects related to any technology stack.
Refer these links for [Guru99](https://www.guru99.com/php-tutorials.html), [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com) for some basic PHP projects.
Browse over [CodePen](https://codepen.io) for Frontend snippets.

Answer (score -2):

I know a site 
https://www.hackerrank.com and 
https://www.hackerearth.com
There are coding challenges from basic to advance of almost every concept. I would recommend to give it a try.